# How to implement message delivery status in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, reliable-message-delivery, ejabberd-saas

I am new to Ejabberd. I want to know whether my message has been delivered to the recipient or not. The client i am using is pidgin.I have gone through the protocol [XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html) I don't know how to implement this(I don't know Erlang). Is there any modules available that implemented this protocol which i can install and use? If its not implemented how can I implement this?

Comment: Message delivery state is completely client side supported feature. You need to enable it from client side. So, iOS xmppframework & Android smack are widely used to build chat application for apps.

Comment: you should use Smack https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XEP-0184 is completely client-side.  No special server functionality is required: only the clients need to support it.

Unfortunately, it seems like Pidgin doesn't support it; see [ticket #6940](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/6940) in their issue tracker. Someone who knows Python would have to work on that.

Comment: Can you suggest any client that support message delivery status?